# Vue dynamically generate slots

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, phpstorm

I need to generate slots from an array which I create dynamically.

I manage to do so with this code:

```
<template v-for="(department,id) in departments" v-slot:[id]="record">
    <template v-if="record.departments.includes(id)">
        <i class="fas fa-check text-success"></i>
    </template>
</template>
```

However, PhpStorm doesn't like it, and I get the following error:

```
http://www.w3.org/19999/XSL/Transform? Alt+Enter

Namespace 'v-slot' is not bound
This inspection checks for unbound namespace prefixes in XML.
```

[image]

[image]

I use Vue version 2.6.10 and PhpStorm 2017.3.6

In terms of functionality, everything is fine, so I guess it is just a generic warning of PhpStorm.
Any idea how can I disable it?

Answer (score 1):

The IDE version you are using provides no support for Vue.js slots; this particular issue ([WEB-37732](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-37732)) is fixed in 2019.2; full support for slots is available since 2019.3 (but the slots generated dynamically won't be completed/resolved, the IDE static code analysis can't handle the stuff only available in runtime).

You can disable the **XML | Unbound XML namespace prefix** inspection as workaround

Comment: So even if I update my PhpStorm to latest versions it will not be solved?

Comment: you won't see the "Namespace 'v-slot' is not bound" error, but your slots won't be recognized